# Finding React Components nested inside html elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to write a reusable component so as to use in future projects. The code I have written works so long as the component "T" is not nested inside html elements.

The localize.js I have written is as follows;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Localizeit = (props) => {
  let textWithLanguageProps = React.Children.map(props.children, function(child) {
    let { s } = child.props; 
    if (React.isValidElement(child)){
        return React.cloneElement(child, {lang : props.data[s]} );
      } 
      return child;
  });
  return (
    <div>
      {textWithLanguageProps}
    </div>
  )
}

const T = ({lang}) => (
  <span>{lang}</span>
)


export { Localizeit , T};
```

In the component in which I am using my translation components I wrap everything that's going to be rendered inside   and then the component checks whether there is a valid react element. If there is then they rendered with the props lang along with the string. This works so long as the component is not nested. I haven't been able come up with a solution to this problem. Do I have to go in depth and check if the html element has a nested react component ?

demo.js is as follows ;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Localizeit, T } from './localize';

const en = {
            hello: "hello world",
            works: "it works weirdly enough"
           }

const es = {
            hello: "hola mundo",
            works: "funciona bastante raro"
           }
const tr = {
            hello: "merhaba dunya",
            works: "garip bir sekilde calisiyor."
           }


class Demo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lang: en
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Localizeit data={this.state.lang}>
          <button onClick={() => this.setState({ lang: en })}>en</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.setState({ lang: tr })}>tr</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.setState({ lang: es })}>es</button>
          <h1>react-localizeit Demo</h1>
          <T s="hello" />
          <br />
          <p>Following doesn't work</p>
          <span><T s="works" /></span>
        </Localizeit>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

A working demo can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ly13j24jom).

Comment: If you want to pass something to every child down the tree you need to define it in the Context. Check out react's Context API

Comment: @SrThompson This is the first time I have heard about it! Thanks a lot. Digging into it now.

Comment: I see you use the `React.cloneElement` strategy. If you use `function as child` or `render props` I am sure that is also feasible approach to what you want.

Comment: I have been reading about the context but seems like I don't really have to go for it. @Kunukn as you have stated may approach seems to be correct so far. However the problem is that only the components who are not nested gets rendered with the props since isValidElement(child) doesn't check the components in depth. I imagine I could also do isValidElement(child.props.children) but then if the component is further nested on different levels it would become really messy.

Comment: Context "can" be tricky to work with, but it will work on any depth. Render props or functions as children are great, they are easier to understand and work with and more explicit, but it will get messier the further down you go in the tree. It's your call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a working prototype in render props version. Here I can nest as I want and it still works.

```
const en = {
  hello: "hello world",
  works: "it works weirdly enough"
};
const es = {
  hello: "hola mundo",
  works: "funciona bastante raro"
};
const tr = {
  hello: "merhaba dunya",
  works: "garip bir sekilde calisiyor."
};
const data = { en, es, tr };

class Localize extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lang: props.initialLanguage || "en"
    };
  }
  render() {
    if(!this.props.data) return null;

    return this.props.render({
      selectedLanguage: this.state.lang, 
      onChange: lang => this.setState({ lang }),
      dict: (this.props.data[this.state.lang]) || {}
    });
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <Localize
    data={data}
    initialLanguage="en"
    render={({ dict, onChange, selectedLanguage}) => (
      <div>

        <h1>localize</h1>
        <div>You have selected: {selectedLanguage}</div>

        <button onClick={() => onChange("en")}>en</button>
        <button onClick={() => onChange("es")}>es</button>
        <button onClick={() => onChange("tr")}>tr</button>
        <div>{dict.hello}</div>
        <div>{dict.works}</div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <span>{dict.hello}</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>{dict.works}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
  />
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Sandbox example
https://codesandbox.io/s/218vx9oo5r

Comment: Awesome! I hadn't thought of it. Thanks for the new perspective!

Answer (score 0):

React component type is a function rather then a regular component which is a string.

This is my solution for it:

```
function buildChildrenWithProps(children, props) {
    return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {

        // if not a valid Component
        if (typeof child.type !== 'function') {
            return child;
        }

        return React.cloneElement(child, Object.assign({}, child.props, props));
    });
}
```

And the usage is this:

```
render(){
    const _children = buildChildrenWithProps(this.props.children, {/*props*/});

    return (
       <div>{_children}</div>
    );
}
```

Comment: That wasn't the actual question. The problem is checking whether there are any nested react components inside it and in how to spot them in different nested levels. I appreciate the effort though!